# Can you equate the diffusivity constant in random walks with the one in Brownian motion (Einstein relation)?

Tags: probability, diffusion, brownian-motion

In an unbiased random walk in one dimension, the coefficient of diffusion is $D = l^2/2\tau$, where $l$ is the size of the jump and $\tau$ is time taken for that jump.

In simple Brownian motion, Einstein's relation says that $D = \mu kT$ where $\mu$ is the mobility, $k$ is the Boltzmann constant and $T$ is temperature.

In both cases, it turns out: 
$$ \langle x^2 \rangle = 2Dt$$
So my question is, can we equate the two constants? So, can we say that:
$l^2/2\tau = \mu kT$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  $D$ refers to the same quantity in both expressions.  In fact, equating them is one way to derive the [Einstein-Smoluchowski relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein-Smoluchowski_equation).  See the last section of [these notes](http://physics-server.uoregon.edu/~raghu/TeachingFiles/Winter08Phys352/Notes_Diffusion.pdf) for more details.